# Changing the metrics in console from characters to pixels

Tags: c++, visual-c++, msdn

I'm wondering, is there a way to click the mouse on a console window and get the x y position by **pixels** instead of a character like the console mode is set on?
i.e I click on the (350,250) pixel on the console but the returned position is (56,35) for example, I searched all over google but didn't find anything usefull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get you a bit further along:

1. Call `GetConsoleWindow()` to the the handle to the console that is running your process.
2. Call `GetConsoleFontSize()` to get width and height of the console font in pixels.
3. Call `GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo()` to get the screen buffer size.
4. Call `PeekConsoleInput()` or `ReadConsoleOutput()` to read the contents of the console you should probably read up on [Low-Level Console Input Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684199.aspx) to understand what's going on here.
5. [This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685035.aspx) explains how to get console click events,
6. Now that you know how to get the mouse click coordinates and you have access to the buffer contents of the console it's simple to calculate what character is being clicked by dividing the X & Y cooridinates with the font width and height.